# set up RAID 1 on 2 data hard disks in Ubuntu Server 22.04, but it's not functioning properly

Tags: server, raid, mdadm

I'm currently using Ubuntu Server 22.04 with three hard disks - one for the installed OS and two for data storage. I've attempted to set up RAID 1 between the two data hard disks, but I'm encountering an issue. When one of the data hard disks in the RAID experiences a problem, the other hard disk in good condition is also rendered inaccessible. Typically, if one RAID data hard disk fails, we should still be able to access the other data hard disk automatically, correct? Is there a solution to this issue?

**Goal:** 
My goal is to ensure that even if one of the **RAID** data hard disks fails, I can still automatically access the other one without having to rebuild the RAID.

**The solution I have tried:**
I have attempted to address the issue by rebuilding the RAID, which allows me to regain access to the data hard disk in good condition.

**Reference:**
The reference guide I am using is from [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-raid-arrays-with-mdadm-on-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: I found a solution by adding these two commands to the /etc/rc.local file to ensure the system assembles the RAID array status at startup.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by adding these two commands to the `/etc/rc.local` file to ensure the system assembles the RAID array status at startup.

```sh
#!/bin/bash  
mdadm --stop /dev/md0  
mdadm --`assemble --scan  
exit 0
```

Then follow the steps outlined in the attached article.
My reference [Enable rc.local on Ubuntu 20.04](https://wp.secretnest.info/archives/12170)

Answer (score 0):

this is my way of doing software raid

```
sudo mkdir -v /raid_data
sudo mkfs.btrfs -L data -d raid1 -m raid1 -f /dev/sdb /dev/sdc
sudo mount /dev/sdb /raid_data
```

This command creates a btrfs file system named data and mounts it to the /raid_data directory. The -L flag stands for label, which allows you to specify a name for the file system. The -d raid1 flag stands for raid1, which indicates that the file system will be created as a RAID1 array. The -m raid1 flag stands for metadata raid1, which means that the metadata for the file system (such as the file system table) will also be striped across the two disks. The -f flag stands for force, which means that the command will overwrite any existing file system or directory on the disks. The /dev/sdb and /dev/sdc flags specify the two disks that will be used for the RAID1 array.

In fstab you should UUID